# Why do I get accosted for taking photos of a war memorial?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I received the quest "Classic Inspiration" from Michael Angelo and was told to take photos of various landmarks around the Mojave Wasteland. Being the talented courier that I am, I've taken photos of all kinds of landmarks - but for some reason when I try and take a photo of the Boulder City War Memorial I get accosted by Private Kowalski claiming I'm "defacing" it.

He says I'm defacing the memorial, but all I'm doing is taking a picture of it. Why is he so mad about my photography?

Comment: When I saw this in the hot questions sidebar, I fully expected this to be a Photography or Travel SE question.

Comment: @BoogaRoo well there *was* a question about someone being accosted for taking a photo in a store in Portugal recently...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Looks like this is a [bug](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Defacing_the_Humble_Stone). Apparently the camera you use is considered a ranged weapon in game that fires invisible projectiles. These do not affect NPCs, however within the scope of the mission, you are firing a bullet at the war memorial, which (of course) angers him.

Comment: You actually are shooting the memorial! Shooting a photo of the memorial!

Comment: Wait, are you insinuating that a _Bethesda game_ has a _bug_? Surely not! :)

Comment: @reirab Fallout New Vegas is an Obsidian game. Obsidian are well known for making games with massive scope, great stories, and huge amounts of bugs. Bethesda generally do less in all three areas.